# What is Hidden lists in sharepoint and relation with managed metadata

Tags: 2013, 2010, sharepoint-server, taxonomy

Hi what is hidden list in SharePoint 2010 and 2013? and how it is link with managed metadata service application.

Comment: [update for 11/12/2020]
I can't comment (or I would), but the link to the referenced article is now https://info.summit7systems.com/blog/troubleshooting-sharepoints-hidden-list-and-managed-metadata-columns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With SharePoint 2010 and 2013, lists and libraries support lookup columns which appear to retrieve data from the term stores of the Managed Metadata Service. However, using Managed Metadata Columns within a site collection creates a hidden list at the site collection level which contains a subset of term store information at `<site collection URL>/Lists/TaxonomyHiddenList/AllItems.aspx.`

This hidden list is simply one instance of localized storage of copies of external data within a site collection. Accessing this local data enhances performance but sometimes creates issues with incorrect data being presented.

Read more over here: https://info.summit7systems.com/blog/troubleshooting-sharepoints-hidden-list-and-managed-metadata-columns/

Comment: I can't believe how much grief this has caused me. Someone had added 'Everyone' with contribute to the site collection of our intranet. Removing this permission from the site collection seems to have also removed the 'Everyone' Read permission from the hidden TaxonomyHiddenList. Found a link to resolution here. http://sharepointfarmer.com/empty-managed-metadata-fields-for-contributors/

Comment: the link to summit7systems no longer valid