# SharePoint Taxonomy management tools

Tags: sharepoint-server, office-365, taxonomy

Are there any SharePoint taxonomy management tools available (Paid/Free)
We have a quite a heavy usage of taxonomy terms in our projects so looking forwards to tools which can sync across dev, uat, prod servers.

Tools that can enable updates to existing taxonomy import/export from csv,excel or data files etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are several SharePoint taxonomy management tools available, both paid and free, that can help with managing taxonomy terms across different SharePoint environments. There are many other paid tools available but here are few free and paid options:

1. **[TermSet Import/Export to CSV](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-term-sets-168fbc86-7fce-4288-9a1f-b83fc3921c18)**: This is a built-in feature in SharePoint that allows you to import and export taxonomy terms using CSV files. You can export terms from one environment and import them into another or just use that CSV file to check records.
2. **[SharePoint Taxonomy Hidden List](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/175744/what-is-hidden-lists-in-sharepoint-and-relation-with-managed-metadata)**: SharePoint maintains a hidden list called the `TaxonomyHiddenList` which stores the metadata and hierarchy of taxonomy terms. You can use SharePoint APIs or PowerShell scripts to update the terms in this list and synchronize them across environments.
3. **[Sharegate](https://sharegate.com/)**: Sharegate is a popular third-party tool that provides comprehensive SharePoint migration and management capabilities. It includes features for managing taxonomy, allowing you to import, export, and update taxonomy terms across different SharePoint environments. Sharegate is a paid tool.
4. **[Metalogix](https://www.quest.com/metalogix/)**: Metalogix is another third-party tool that specializes in SharePoint migration and management. Metalogix is also a paid tool.
5. **[SharePoint Migration Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/managed-metadata-migration)**: This is a free tool provided by Microsoft that allows you to manage the SharePoint Term Store. It provides a user-friendly interface for importing and exporting terms, updating properties, and managing term sets. You can find Term Store Manager in the SharePoint Online Administration Center.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the PnP Powershell cmdlets to export/import termstore items between environments.

Export-PnpTaxonomy, Import-PnpTaxonomy, Export-PnPTermGroupToXml etc.

https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Export-PnPTaxonomy.html